# Куда делся intel-go/bytebuf?

Tags: golang

Переносил проект на новый компьютер и понял, что не могу подключить bytebuf от intel, на котором все модули работают... на гитхабе просто 404 и нигде не могу найти, как теперь подключать библиотеку? За что ее удалили или intel сами? Одни вопросы, что произошло?

```
go get github.com/intel-go/bytebuf
```

Answer (score 1):

Удалён, т.к. патч принят в основную ветку Go: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/intel-go/bytebuf

> This implementation is deprecated as the patch is merged to the Go
> mainline (https://golang.org/cl/133715)

Используйте стандартный `bytes.Buffer`.